# How to select mutiple checkboxes using selenium webdriver reading data from excel?

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Coded UI for creating some test cases for a web application, while doing the same I have encountered an issue. The page contains 3 tables with mutiple check boxes, I am not able to click on checkboxes reading data from excel.Someone help me to find a solution
Here is my html code:

**Table 1 - HTML:**

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPEC01_01">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input 
                id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPEC01_01_0"
                type="checkbox" 
                name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPEC01_01$0"
                value=" Ambu-bag     ">
             <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPEC01_01_0"> Ambu-bag   </label>
          </td>
          <td>
             <input
                id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPEC01_01_1"
                type="checkbox" 
                name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPEC01_01$1" 
                value=" apnea monitor    ">
             <label 
                for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPEC01_01_1"> apnea monitor  </label>
          </td>
          <td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Table 2 - HTML:**

```
<table id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01">
   //table 2
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_0" 
            type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPOP01_01$0"
            value=" Universal    ">
            <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_0"> Universal   </label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_1" 
               type="checkbox" 
               name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl04$cbl_CCPOP01_01$1" value=" Aspiration    ">
            <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl04_cbl_CCPOP01_01_1"> Aspiration  </label>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my sample code.But not working fine.

**Table 1 - Code:**

```
String valueEquipmentChecklist = data.getEquipmentChecklist().get(rowCnt);//data reading from excel

List<WebElement> equipChecklist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
List<String> equipmentChecklistList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valueEquipmentChecklist.split(",")));

for (String equipmentChecklistCheck : equipmentChecklistList) {
    for (WebElement equipmentChecklistChk : equipChecklist) {

        if (equipmentChecklistChk.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(equipmentChecklistCheck)) {
                if (!equipmentChecklistChk.isSelected()) {
                    equipmentChecklistChk.click();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Table 2 - Code:**

```
String valueOngoingPrecuations = data.getOngoingPrecuations().get(rowCnt);

List<WebElement> ongoingPrecuations = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
List<String> ongoingPrecuationsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(valueOngoingPrecuations.split(",")));

for (String ongoingPrecuationsCheck : ongoingPrecuationsList) {
    for (WebElement ongoingPrecuationsChk : ongoingPrecuations) {

        if (ongoingPrecuationsChk.getAttribute("value").equalsIgnoreCase(ongoingPrecuationsCheck)) {
            if (!ongoingPrecuationsChk.isSelected()) {
                ongoingPrecuationsChk.click();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? and why you have involved excel sheet in this scenario.

Comment: @SreejithaJ Yor question is too broad. Instead of asking solution for both the tables you can reduce the scope of the question to a single table and implement the same logic for the second table.

Answer (score 0):

accoring to HTML you provided value of checkboxes contains spaces, possibly in your excel file this spaces are not exist, so you should delete spaces in value of checkbox before comparing or use "**contains**" instead of "**equals**"